# Data of a struct into a union

Tags: c, struct, unions

I have declared the next union:

```
typedef union
{
   struct
   {
      uint32_t data;
   };
uint8_t w[4];
} xxx_data_t
```

I am trying to access a memory by SPI, which only has an input capacity of 1Byte.
I want to enter the variable `data`, and I have though of descomposing that 32-bits `data` variable into 4 8-bits variables (1Byte each one), thus forming the `w[4]` array.
My question is: is this valid? This creates a descomposition of my 32-bits variable?

**EXAMPLE**

I declare `xxx_DATA_t my_variable`.
`my_variable.data=300` which in hexadecimal is 0x12C. Will the array be `my_variable.w[4]=[0,0,1,44]`??

data (32-bits) = 300 = 0x  00  00  01  2C

w    (4-bits)  ====== = 0x  [0] [0] [1] [44]

Thanks all.

Comment: why don't try it? of course it depends on the endianness

Comment: It's big endian, so the form of the 8-bits array is right. I start to suspect that I am trying to write into a protect area of the memory. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is right. You can write a test program to test it.

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
typedef union
{
   struct
   {
      uint32_t data;
   };
uint8_t w[4];
}data_t;

int main(){
        data_t d = {.data = 0x12c};
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                printf("%d\n", d.w[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

```sh
44
1
0
0
```

Comment: As PHUCLV commented, I tried it in a simple example. More or less as u describe. And yes, the result is just as I posted. Thank you all for your comments/help.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: is this valid?

Yes, you may do type punning between different types using union. Type punning to/from a character type (which `uint8_t` almost certainly is) is always safe. Alignment/padding shouldn't be an issue either, in this specific case.

Please note that you can only do this in C - you *cannot* do it in C++. So think twice before using C++ for hardware-related programming.

> which in hexadecimal is 0x12C. Will the array be my_variable.w[4]=[0,0,1,44]??

It depends on CPU endianess. [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)

So you can either get `00 00 01 2C` on a Big Endian computer such as Power PC, or you can get `2C 01 00 00` on a Little Endian computer such as x86.

As for what endianess you actually *want*, it is the *network* endianess. In case of SPI, network endianess is the same as the byte order that the part you are communicating with expects. You have to look that up in a datasheet, in case it's a "dumb" part like an ADC, display or similar. If it's a "smart" part like another MCU, then you can probably specify the network endianess yourself.